# Adapting JavaScript into Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, polymer

**IGNORE THIS PART EDIT 4 IS THE MOST PERTINENT** (see below)

loving Polymer! Just trying to adapt three functions into my code:

```
Polymer('my-element', {

// JavaScript for Box (Also Beta)
                unhidePanel: function(panelName) {
                    var panel = this.$.panelName;
                    var hidden = panel.getAttribute('isPanelHidden');

                    if (hidden == "true") {
                        panel.style.display="block";
                        panel.setAttribute('isPanelHidden', "false");
                    }
                    else {
                        panel.style.display="none";
                        panel.setAttribute('isPanelHidden', "true");
                    }
                },

                voteDefPercent: function(val,defid) {
                    var def = this.$.defid;

                    var upvotes = parseInt(def.getAttribute("data-upvotes"),10) + val;
                    var votes = parseInt(def.getAttribute("data-votes"),10) + 1;

                    var percent = Math.round((upvotes / votes) * 100);

                    def.setAttribute('data-upvotes', upvotes);
                    def.setAttribute('data-votes', votes);

                    def.value = percent;
                },

                voteidPercent: function(val,tagid) {
                    var tag = this.$.tagid;

                    var upvotes = parseInt(tag.getAttribute("data-upvotes"),10) + val;
                    var votes = parseInt(tag.getAttribute("data-votes"),10) + 1;

                    var percent = Math.round((upvotes / votes) * 100);

                    tag.style.backgroundSize = percent + "%, 100%, 100%, 100%";

                    tag.setAttribute('data-upvotes', upvotes);
                    tag.setAttribute('data-votes', votes);
                },

                // End JavaScript

});
```

These functions were originally JavaScript, with a couple changes. The code isn't working for any of the three so I'm wondering if there is a syntax problem or some other thing I need to change. Is it possible to pass variables using the form `onclick: {{ functionName(variableName) }}` or is there some sort of other special syntax? Thanks so much!!

**EDIT 1**

Example of HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default tag-upvote" on-click="voteidPercent(1,'sample-tag-1')"></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tag-link" id="sample-tag-1" data-upvotes="0" data-votes="0">Official Symbol</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tag-downvote" on-click="voteidPercent(0,'sample-tag-1')"></button>
```

**EDIT 2**

The system has three generic functions which are called many times by many different components. I have a feeling getting just one of them working will help me determine on my own how to fix the rest.

The HTML shown in EDIT 1 describes a group of buttons. Only the center button is visible unless the user hovers over it, splitting it into three buttons.

The three buttons are: (Upvote Button)(Link Button)(Downvote Button)

Depending on the percentage of "upvotes" vs. "total votes", when the user is no longer hovering over the button, the original center button is the only one remaining, but the percentage red or green changes depending on the percentage of upvotes vs. total votes.

There are about 50 - 80 of these button groups per page so passing each as an individual function is a tad cumbersome, but each has an individual value.

In order to store/calculate the percentage, the center button has two attributes "data-upvotes" and "data-votes". Further, whenever the upvote button is pressed it passes a parameter 1 (to add to the upvote count) and the name of the center button, whereas the downvote button passes a 0 (to add to the upvote count) and the name of the center button.

I can't think of an efficient way to do this without parameters and desperately need some pointing in the right direction. Thank you so much and thanks to Dirk for his help getting this far!

**EDIT 3**

I've given this a few days and I'm still lost. My current HTML example is as follows:

```
<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" isPanelHidden="true" on-tap="{{ unhidePanel }}" panelName="relational-tags-area-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" id="category-button"></span></button></p>
```

And then my refined JavaScript:

```
unhidePanel: function() {
      var panelName = this.$.getAttribute('panelName');


      var hidden = panel.getAttribute('isPanelHidden');
      console.log(panelName);

      if (hidden == "true") {
           panel.style.display="block";
           panel.setAttribute('isPanelHidden', "false");
      }
      else {
           panel.style.display="none";
           panel.setAttribute('isPanelHidden', "true");
      }
},
```

I'm getting an "Uncaught Type error: undefined is not a function" at `var panelName = this.$.getAttribute('panelName');`

**EDIT 4**

Ignoring everything I've done above, I've run into a larger issue of the same type. Is there any way at all to use JavaScript within a Polymer element? Can I do anything along these lines:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(function() {
        var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000, 400, 1);
        sys.parameters({gravity:true});
        sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport");
        var animals = sys.addNode('Animals',{'color':'red','shape':'dot','label':'Animals'});
    });
</script>
```

(This uses arbor.js, which was declared above this statement)

If not, is there a quick fix or work around that won't require rewriting all of my code? Thanks so much, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If 'not working' means that your functions are not called, then indeed it's because your event declarations are wrong (you should have posted the HTML code instead).

1. You cannot pass parameters to the event handlers
2. The event attribute is named `on-click`

So you need to write `on-click="{{functionName}}"`. Please refer to the [delcarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) section in the Polymer documentation.

Comment: I'm confused as to if there is any way to write non-specific functions if I can't pass parameters... Is there any possible work around?

Comment: Since this is a new topic, please ask a new question describing what data you need to be available in your event function and where this data is coming from. A SO comment has way too little space for answering such a general question with possibly many solutions.

Comment: I'm really sorry, apparently I've been blocked from asking questions by the system (low voted questions, which I get, a couple of them have been stupid and that's my fault). I will try to include more detail in this question as another edit, but I understand that it should really be a new question.

Comment: An event object is implicitly passed to every event handler function. This object contains a property _target_ which refers to the element that triggered the event. Since you can then access this elements attributes, it is possible to pass parameters to the callback function via _data-..._ attributes.